# Is niyoga the same as surrogacy?

Tags: mahabharata, ayurveda

Does niyoga mean surrogacy?
In the Mahabharata vyasa did tubectomy like that only.
In case of Vichitravirya's wives did vyasa do surrogacy?

Does AyurVeda tell about this niyoga?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do niyoga is surrogacy?

Yes, niyoga is surrogacy:

> [Manu 9.59](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201419.html) - If a wife doesn't have any children, then when she is given permission by her elders, she may obtain the desired children from her younger brother-in-law or a sapinda.

However, niyoga is now forbidden in kali yuga:

> Apastamba 2.10.27.4 - That [Niyoga] is [at present] forbidden on account of the weakness of [men's] senses.